# How do I prepare my new bathtub alcove?

Tags: tile, waterproofing

I will be expanding my bathroom and moving the bathtub, meaning I need to prepare a new bathtub alcove.

I know how to frame and plumb - but preparing for tile is new to me.

I know that there are different products out there to use to prepare for tile, such as concrete backer-board which would apply direct to the studs and get sealed with thinset, vs. waterproof membranes which would be applied directly to greenboard without the backerboard.

What I don't know is - what are the advantages/disadvantages to each approach?  Is one better than the other?

The plan is to use ceramic and glass tiles - does that make a difference?

Comment: fyi, thinset is an adhesive, not a sealer.

Comment: @DA01 Am I getting my products wrong? I thought the backerboard was installed with an expansion gap which was then filled with thinset...

Comment: I've used thinset for that, but it doesn't seal anything. It's a mortar. You'd still need some sort of waterproof sealant in the 'sandwich'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, greenboard is no longer accepted as a suitable product for wet areas. It has been replaced with "purpleboard" or glass-backed products without paper for mold growth.

Consider doing to tub alcove in a cementicious board like Hardi500 or a fiber-glass backed gypsum like DensGuard.

Do not apply a vapor barrier behind these if you intend to seal them from the room side. This will promote the dreaded "moisture sandwich." where any moisture which *does* get through the first barrier cannot escape the second.

From recently doing a similar project I am a supporter of the Kerdi membrane. You set the wall boards and seam them as usual (any board will do, but I like mold-resistant and water-resistant board)... then you "shingle" on the kerdi membrane with thinset.

**EDIT:** I changed where I said "blueboard" to "purpleboard" as some googling showed I was using the wrong slang....

Comment: Kerdi is good. I also like Redgard (which is a paint-on membrane)

Comment: Some mold resistant drywall products are green, some are blue.  But don't worry, I won't use any for the tub alcove.